# C#, WPF - HelixToolkit camera manipulation

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using Helix-toolkit in my WPF project to draw 3D lines.
What I have already done are:

1. Adding the namespace to WPF: `xmlns:Helix="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"`
2. Adding the control to WPF: `<Helix:HelixViewport3D x:Name="HelixViewport3D" />`
3. Adding the 3D lines to the Helix in C#: `Point3DCollection _points;
   LinesVisual3D _lines = new LinesVisual3D();
   _lines.Points = _points;
   HelixViewport3D.Children.Add(_lines);`
4. Zooming and Changing camera location:
     I used the following code for zooming: `HelixViewport3D.ZoomExtents(1000);`

   I used the following code to change view: `HelixViewport3D.CameraController.CameraUpDirection = new Vector3D(0, 0, 1);`  `HelixViewport3D.CameraController.CameraTarget = new Point3D(0, 70, 0);`

Now I want to add some buttons to my project which will give fixed viewing command like TopView, BottomView, FrontView, BackView, LeftView, RightView etc.

The Button will look like the following

[image]

But I am confused with the parameters of `HelixViewport3D.CameraController.CameraUpDirection`, `HelixViewport3D.CameraController.CameraLookDirection`, `HelixViewport3D.CameraController.CameraTarget`

How can I give those fixed view commands from C#.

Answer (score 0):

These are my SharpGL camera settings for the views

```
<Camera:LookAtCamera x:Key="CameraLeft" Position="-10, 0, 0" Target="0, 0, 0" UpVector="0, 1, 0" />
<Camera:LookAtCamera x:Key="CameraRight" Position="10, 0, 0" Target="0, 0, 0" UpVector="0, 1, 0" />
<Camera:LookAtCamera x:Key="CameraTop" Position="0, 10, 0" Target="0, 0, 0" UpVector="0, 0, -1" />
<Camera:LookAtCamera x:Key="CameraBottom" Position="0, -10, 0" Target="0, 0, 0" UpVector="0, 0, 1" />
<Camera:LookAtCamera x:Key="CameraBack" Position="0, 0, -10" Target="0, 0, 0" UpVector="0, 1, 0" />
<Camera:LookAtCamera x:Key="CameraFront" Position="0, 0, 10" Target="0, 0, 0" UpVector="0, 1, 0" />
```

I set the helixtoolkit aside a while ago and started using SharpGL, But these Camera Positions, Targets, and UpVectors should help.